# What is wrong with my SQL command?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to put the query result into a PowerPoint file like the below

```
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'SQLCMD -Q "Select * From test_tbl" -O "E:test_tbl.ppt"'
```

but it is not working.

Below is the summary that I am getting

```
**output**

Sqlcmd: Warning: '-O' is an obsolete option and is ignored.
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Server SUMERU-49484E24, Line 1
Invalid object name 'TableName'.
NULL
```

Before executing this query I have already enabled the xp_cmdshell by using sp_configure.

Also I have the .ppt file in the proper location.

I have doing this just for my own sake of experiment.

Kindly help me in executing the same.

Using SQL Server 2005.

Edit:

I have changed the query like the below

```
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'SQLCMD -Q "Select * From test_tbl" -s "SUMERU-49484E24\SQLEXPRESS2008" -d "test" -E -o "D:t2.ppt"'
```

But the below is the error in the pptfile

```
HResult 0xFDC, Level 11, State 1
Cannot open database requested in login 'test'. Login fails.
HResult 0x4818, Level 14, State 1
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.
HResult 0x4, Level 16, State 1
Shared Memory Provider: I/O Error detected in read/write operation [4]. 
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Native Client : Communication link failure.
```

Thanks

Comment: so obviously, you cannot use integrated Windows security - use a specific SQL login (-U username) and the appropriate password (-P topsecret) instead

Answer (score 2):

I see a few problems:

- the parameter for `sqlcmd` to define the output file is `-o` (lowercase) - not the `-O` (uppercase) you're using
- you're not defining what server and database to connect to - you need to add `-S (servername)` and `-d (database name)` to your SQLCMD command line
- you're not defining how to connect security-wise - either supply `-E` for a trusted connection (integrated Windows security) or define user and password using `-U (login)` and `-P (password)`

Comment: *> implying Windows has security*

Comment: Sir, I have now tried with EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'SQLCMD -Q "Select * From test_tbl" -s "SUMERU-49484E24\SQLEXPRESS2008" -d "test" -E -o "D:t2.txt"'

but the result is 

HResult 0xFDC, Level 11, State 1
Cannot open database requested in login 'test'. Login fails.
HResult 0x4818, Level 14, State 1
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.
HResult 0x4, Level 16, State 1
Shared Memory Provider: I/O Error detected in read/write operation [4]. 
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Native Client : Communication link failure.


help me pls

Comment: @siddhu: so obviously, you cannot use integrated Windows security - use a specific SQL login and the appropriate password instaead